# Not getting correct result while giving input as runtime input

Tags: java

[image]

I am new to java. i have tried input as arguments at that time there is execution is perfect. When i am try to give input as runtime input it gives only "else" result. what is the mistake i have done? and How to solve this?

Comment: Posting pictures is ok but please post your code as text if you ask a question so it´s possible to copy it.

Comment: you can't compare strings with == use .equals()

Comment: On top of what the other comments said, you can also add print statements right after the input appeared, to output what the input was. To confirm you got what you think you got.

Comment: `==` does compare the object reference so if this is the same field on your space. You need to use `string.equals(string)` to compare values of a string. Of cause you can use `==` for non-object/primitiv types/values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void h(){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What you Want to do = ");
    String k = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the value of a = ");
    int a = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the value of b = ");
    int b = s.nextInt();

    if(("p").equals(k) || (("+").equals(k))){
       sum = a+b;
        System.out.println("Sum = "+sum);
    }
    else if(("s").equals(k) || (("-").equals(k))){
        sum = a-b;
        System.out.println("Sum = "+sum);
    }
    else if(("m").equals(k) || (("*").equals(k))){
        sum = a*b;
        System.out.println("Sum = "+sum);
    }
    else if(("d").equals(k) || (("/").equals(k))){
        sum = a/b;
        System.out.println("Sum = "+sum);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Enter the correct work to do");
    }
```